# Runtime Exception can be thrown?

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

I have written a class in which i am trying to throw a runtime exception. The code is as follows

```
public class ExceptionTest 

{

    public static void ReadFile() throws RuntimeException, FileNotFoundException{
    try{

    BufferedReader b =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("I:\\Workspace\\Basic Java\\bin\\Exceptions\\List To Read.txt"));
    String s = b.readLine();
    while(s!=null){
        System.out.println(s);
        s=b.readLine();
    }
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e){
        throw e;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        throw e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

And my main class looks like

```
public class TheMain {
public static void main(String args[]){
    ExceptionTest.ReadFile();
}
}
```

my  doubt is can we throw a run time exception?
Please help

Comment: yes you can. You can throw anything that extends Throwable - check the javadocs.

Comment: if you can not recover from a runtime exception, then you can throw it

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

Comment: Yes, you can throw a RuntimeException. You also said, "My doubt is we are not handling the thrown error in the main class yet my JVM is not throwing an error?" What's the thrown error? Can you provide more information about what that error is, and what you actually see?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. We need to handle it in the main

Comment: Catching and just re-throwing like this should be avoided as it servers no purpose. If you can't do something useful to recover, just let any possible RuntimeException float to the top and out of your Main to the VM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RunTimeException` is an [unchecked exception](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129). You can throw it, but you don't necessarily have to, unless you want to explicitly specify to the user of your API that this method can throw an unchecked exception. But even this doesn't seem to be necessary if you mention this fact (that the method can throw a RunTimeException) in the javadoc for this method.

So, in short, yes, you can throw it, but you don't have to, as it does not provide you any given advantage and costs you a few extra lines of code

Answer (score 4):

You can throw a `java.lang.RuntimeException` (or any derived exception), as it is a normal exception. The difference to other exceptions is that you do not need to mention it in the list of thrown but uncaught exceptions a method can throw, ie.

```
public void foo(int bar) throws RuntimeException {
    throw new RuntimeException("foo(bar)");
}
```

has the same effect as

```
public void foo(int bar) {
    throw new RuntimeException("foo(bar)");
}
```

Despite that, a `java.lang.RuntimeException` (or anything derived) behaves like a normal exception, ie. it terminates your program, if not caught.

Answer (score 3):

```
throw new RuntimeException('someMessagehere')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Runtime exception should never be thrown deliberately. Java has categorised exception in Checked Exception and Unchecked i.e Runtime exception. We should always throw checked exception. The unchecked exceptions should never occur in the program as they are supposed to be handled programmatically and not by throwing them.

Comment: This is a strong matter of opinion. There are a lot of good arguments for why Checked Exceptions were a bad idea.

Comment: Checked Exception mandates the client(Calling system) to handle them and show appropriate error message for the Exceptional scenario. I would like to know the good arguments why Checked Exception was a bad idea:)

Comment: There's lots of resources out there on google (for instance here: https://blog.philipphauer.de/checked-exceptions-are-evil/). i'm not necessarily trying to convince you that checked exceptions are totally evil... but I strongly disagree with your statement that "ideally runtime exceptions should never be thrown deliberately".